Existence of probability distributions whose averages have sizeable deviations from the mean?
This question is a follow-up question to this old question of mine and this partial solution.

Question. Does there exist a (real or even integer) random variable $X$ with finite first moment $\mu$ such that if $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are iid random variables with $X$'s distribution then
$$\sum_n \mathbf{P} \big[ |\overline{X}_n - \mu | > 1 \big] = +\infty$$
where $\overline{X}_n = \frac1n(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$ is the $n$-th mean.

Note. Please feel free to edit the title of this question if you can find a more descriptive one.
